# How to correctly get derived class object from base object in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, relational-database, entity-relationship

I'm newcomer in django, and here is question:

I have model class:

```
def Client(models.User) # django.contrib.auth.User
   company_name=models.CharField()
```

How could I get Client object when I have user object (and user is client)? One way is to filter objects by username:

```
user=request.user
client=Client.objects.filter(username=user.username)
```

But I think there is some different and more beautiful method to do this in django, because user is client (they are related one-to-one in database), is one there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation on inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance):

> If you have a `User` that is also a `Client`, you can get from the `User` object to the `Client` object by using the lower-case version of the model name:

```
my_user = User.objects.get(username = 'foobar')
client = my_user.client
```

If the `User` instance is not a `Client`, you'll get a `Client.DoesNotExist` exception.

Comment: This does not help. If I know that I have a `Client`, then I could use client=Client.objects.get(....)` in the first place. In most cases you haven N child classes.